# Date differences between Chrome & Firefox

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, date, firefox

I am getting an odd difference between Firefox and Chrome using the same bit of code:

```
var d = new Date('2019', '4', '4');
```

In Chrome I get the expected result: May 04 2019

In Firefox I get the following result: 2019-05-03

Why is Firefox 1 day out?

Here are some screenshots from the consoles in both browsers:

Chrome:
[image: Chrome]

Firefox:
[image: Firefox]

Comment: its time zone related, chrome looks to use utc whereas firefox uses local time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are the same date/time. The difference is that the first one is being shown to you in BST (British Summer Time, GMT+0100), and the second one is being shown to you in GMT (the `Z` on the end tells you that).

The `Date` constructor constructs dates in local time, which for you apparently is currently BST (for me, too :-) ). Since you haven't specified a time, it defaults to midnight. Firefox just shows you that in GMT, which is an hour earlier than midnight BST, hence the previous day.

---

Side note: The arguments you provide to `new Date` should be numbers, not strings. Although [the date constructor](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-date-year-month-date-hours-minutes-seconds-ms) will coerce for you, it's best practice not to rely on it.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191714/discussion-on-answer-by-t-j-crowder-date-differences-between-chrome-firefox).

Comment: Many thanks for the help - you mentioning that Date should accept numbers not strings helped me eliminate a different bug whilst making this code better, so thanks.